# MDC-web Howto build individual css files pr component

Tags: web, material-components

For the MDC-Web project webpack bundles all components into a `node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.css` For debug, understanding and integration, I try to build individual components, e.g. `mdc-drawer.css`

The documentation at section css indicates this is possible, but not how https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web. So one could obtain e.g. `dist/mdc-drawer.css` and `dist/mdc-drawer.min.css`

I guess this should be done in the config of the webpack build https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Anyone have tips on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the root of the `material-components-web` project, run the command

`npm run build`

This generates css/js files pr. component, in dir `build`

Serve for my purpose. Have very limited experience with webpack/mdc-web, so if better ways exits don't hesitate to add them.